# SQL Error [42P07]: ERROR: relation "table1" already exist

Tags: amazon-redshift, dbeaver

Running a query to create a table, in the framework DBeaver v22, the error returns from a random table, every time I run the SQL script and it hits a query to create a table.

The script has a few thousands of lines, lots of drops and creates tables and. the very same error happens randomly when a CREATE query gets executed.

At the time I created this thread, I executed the script and it returned error in the creation of table1.
But It could have been any other. It doesn`t seem to be an error in he syntax/grammar of my SQL, but somehow in the engine of DBeaver 22.2. Because the error returns in a random table as per script execution.

SQL Error [42P07]: ERROR: relation "table1" already exist

Even though I added the following query to DROP TABLE, right before the one to CREATE table, the error still returns, when the query to create gets executed.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sandbox.table1;
CREATE TABLE sandbox.table1 as ();
```

I wonder if it takes a long time to drop the table so that, the create command line returns error
Is that possible to be the cause ?
Do I need a timer to wait for RDBMS fully drop the table?

SQL Error [42P07]: ERROR: relation "table1" already exist

Answer (score 0):

Accessing further logs I`ve identified the root cause was permission error.
As It couldn't delete then creating table caused the error

org.jkiss.dbeaver.model
Error
Wed Dec 07 11:38:44 BRT 2022
SQL Error [42501]: ERROR: permission denied for relation table1